# Query node-label topology from Yarn via REST API [MapR 6.1/Hadoop-2.7]

Tags: rest, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, mapr

There is a Java and CLI-interface to query Yarn RM for node-to-nodelabel (and inverse) mappings. Is there a way to do this via the REST-API as well?
An initial RM-API search revealed only node-label based job submissions as an option.

Sadly that is actually broken in MapR-Hadoop (6.1 as of 6/6/19), so my code has to work around that, by implementing the correct scheduling itself. This works (barely - more broken APIs here as well) using the YarnClient Java API.

But as I want to schedule jobs against different resource managers at the same time, behind firewalls, the REST-API is the most compelling option to achieve this, and the YarnClient API's RPC backend can't be easily transported.

My current worst-case solution would be to parse the YARN-WebUI in some way.

Comment: Hmm.... are you stuck with Yarn? It sounds like your needs are outside its design scope.

Comment: Also, can you hit me directly (tdunning@mapr) so we can raise a support ticket if there is something broken in the MapR packaging of YARN?

Comment: The issues are already being tracked under MAPRYARN-191.

Comment: Regarding the design -- I have a working solution using YARN, I merely want to make it more portable, by accessing YARN using the REST-API. I have found some undocumented API, that appears to give per-node node-labeling, now to see if MapR-YARN correctly provides values at these endpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found so far:
Request `/ws/v1/cluster/nodes` - this gets you all nodes.

FlatMap/Distinct on each `node`'s `nodeLabels`, if you need just the list of node labels. Filter by nodeLabel, if you need all nodes for a specified label.

This does mean, that you always have to query **all** nodes, then sort/filter/arrange by `NodeLabels`, which is a lot of client-side magic. But apparently there's no [`GetNodesToLabel`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/api/ApplicationClientProtocol.html#getNodeToLabels(org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.protocolrecords.GetNodesToLabelsRequest)) or even [`GetClusterNodeLabels`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/api/ApplicationClientProtocol.html#getClusterNodeLabels(org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.protocolrecords.GetClusterNodeLabelsRequest)) to help us out.

I assume [`getLabelsToNodes`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/client/api/YarnClient.html#getLabelsToNodes(java.util.Set)) is just a client-side implementation, as the protocol doesn't define the API, so that's right out the window for REST, unless implemented in the WebService.